# Javascript Regex to extract international phone numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for some guidance in how to extract international phone numbers (will differ in the number of digits) from a data-id attribute.

Basically want to develop a regex that extracts the phone number that appears between the underscore and @ symbol.

Thanks.

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="GDTQm message-in focusable-list-item" data-id="false_13196065555@c.us_2221BD2F26195BACD1X06ED679AB5A00"></div>
// Desired output = 13196065555


<div tabindex="-1" class="GDTQm message-in focusable-list-item" data-id="false_972545725555@c.us_42C3B19604A314532343D9E33FE164F7"></div>
// Desired output = 972545725555


<div tabindex="0" class="GDTQm _2iwLX message-in focusable-list-item" data-id="false_5215520105555@c.us_3AFD99420CD1DX267FC2">/div>
// Desired output = 5215520105555
```

Comment: Why not use basic string manipulation instead?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/TaqHei/1 - `_(.*)@`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
data-id="[^\d"]+(\d+)
```

and take the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/b9knqy/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use simple string manipulation:

```js
const data = 'false_5215520105555@c.us_3AFD99420CD1DX267FC2';

const phoneNumber = data.split('@')[0].split('_')[1];

console.log(phoneNumber);
```

Nevertheless, if you want to use regex:

```js
const data = 'false_5215520105555@c.us_3AFD99420CD1DX267FC2';
const match = data.match(/([0-9]+)@/)[1];
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
string.prototype.match(/(?<=_)[\d]+?(?=@)/);
```

using element id :

```
function getNumber (element) {
  return element.id.match(/(?<=_)[\d]+?(?=@)/)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let s = "false_13196065555@c.us_2221BD2F26195BACD1X06ED679AB5A00"
let regex = /_(.*)@/;
regex.exec(s)[1]; // "13196065555"
```

Comment: You just copied the @Mosh Feu comment on the question. At least, give him the credit.

Comment: I didn't notice @Mosh Feu's comment when I wrote my answer, but yes I agree with Mosh's comment.